# problem with z-index

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a page with some menus:

First:
[image]

And second:

[image]

In the first image you can see the page, but my problem is that when I open the menus (written with jQuery and CSS), all the page elements are going down. What is problem?

Edit:

i change it to position absolute instead of z-indcex but don't have any affect.

Comment: Voting to close. This is clearly a RTFM question meaning the OP has not bothered to read even the most basic introduction into box model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use position:absolute on the menus parent elements (usually ul), if you provide some code I can be more specific.

Comment: and also set the z-index value

Comment: Actually setting the z-index is only neccesary if the elements below have it. If the elements below have z-index and the menus have z-index then you need to make the menus z-index value higher, but if none of them have z-index then you don't need it on the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Please set z-index of menu is large for eg 9999 and then try..

Comment: ohh.. i understood a wrong issue...
This is for a menu back ground getting over World Map..
and the solution of this is may be you not set the position of menu to absolute

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the z-index value, your menus should have "position:absolute" style if you don't want them to affect other elements' positioning on your page.